# Do i need to open each client message in new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have application that host `WCF` service:

```
namespace ServiceLibrary
{

        public delegate void StatusEventHandler(Capture capture);

        // You have created a class library to define and implement your WCF service.
        // You will need to add a reference to this library from another project and add 
        // the code to that project to host the service as described below.  Another way
        // to create and host a WCF service is by using the Add New Item, WCF Service 
        // template within an existing project such as a Console Application or a Windows 
        // Application.

        [ServiceContract()]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string ClientMsg(string str);
        }

            [ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
        public class service1 : IService1
        {
            public event StatusEventHandler CapturingEvent;
            public event StatusEventHandler OnProcessExitedEvent;
            public event StatusEventHandler OnFinishEvent;

            public string ClientMsg(string str)
            {
                return DoWork(str);
            }

            private DoWork(string str)
            }
               MyClass obj = New MyClass();
               obj.Start(str); /// Do my job
            }
        }
    }
```

The client send string to my server and i am opening instance of my class and this class open process, do my job and return to the client the process id number.
this server received messages from multiple clients so i wonder if i need to open new thread each time i received client message to avoid situation that several clients send message to the server in the same time.

This is how i am open the server connection in main form:

```
private void connect()
{
    try
    {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            // Returns a list of ipaddress configuration
            IPHostEntry ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            // Get machine ipaddress
            IPAddress _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(tbServerIp.Text);

            // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be started
            urlService = "net.tcp://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8000/CapturesService";

            // Instruct the ServiceHost that the type that is used is a ServiceLibrary.service1
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));
            //ServiceLibrary.service1 serviceInstance = new ServiceLibrary.service1();
            //serviceInstance.CapturingEvent += serviceInstance_StartCapturingEvent;
            //serviceInstance.OnProcessExitedEvent += serviceInstance_OnProcessExitedEvent;
            //host = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance);
            host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
            host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
            host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
            host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);

            // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // <- Very crucial

            // Add a endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceLibrary.IService1), tcpBinding, urlService);

            // A channel to describe the service. Used with the proxy scvutil.exe tool
            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
            metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (metadataBehavior == null)
            {
                // Create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
                metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8001/CapturesService");
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                metadataBehavior.ToString();
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                urlMeta = metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl.ToString();
            }

            host.Open();
            isConnected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (asyncWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                // Notify the worker thread that a cancel has been requested.
                // The cancel will not actually happen until the thread in the
                // DoWork checks the bwAsync.CancellationPending flag, for this
                // reason we set the label to "Cancelling...", because we haven't
                // actually cancelled yet.
                asyncWorker.CancelAsync();
            }

            host.Close();
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

private int StartTsharkProcess(Capture capture)
{
    ProcessExitedEvent += Capture_ProcessExitedEvent;
    string args = string.Format("-i {0} host {1} {2} -a duration:300 -w {3}",
        Interface.interfaceNumber,
        capture.machineIpAddress,
        getTsharkFilter(),
        Path.Combine(LocalPath.localPath, capture.fileName));

    int processId = InvokeProcess(WiresharkProcesses.Tshark, args);
    return processId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this server received messages from multiple clients so i wonder if i need to open new thread each time i received client message to avoid situation that several clients send message to the server in the same time.

`ServiceBehavior` attribute has [ConcurrencyMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx).

> This property indicates whether an instance of a service can handle one thread or multiple threads that execute concurrently, and if single-threaded, whether reentrancy is supported.

[The default service behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751438.aspx) has `ConcurrencyMode` with `ConcurrencyMode.Single` value. So, if it is necessary to allow multiple calls at once, please use `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` with notice:

> No synchronization guarantees are made. Because other threads can change your service object at any time, **you must handle synchronization** and state consistency at all times.

Note: if service methods perform long-running tasks, clients might have a timeout.

Comment: My client send the command to server and die immediately after received the respond from the server, can i have good tutorial of synchronization and state consistency ?

Comment: Why after change to ConcurrencyMode.Multiple the client didn't received server message ?

Comment: @user2214609, could you please provide some diagnostics?

Comment: See my update under ServiceLibrary (i have changed ServiceBehavior) and private void connect (i am using the constructor)

Comment: I have changed InstanceContextMode.PerSession, My class only start process and return the process id, i have checked it with debugger and it return the correct value

Comment: See StartTsharkProcess function at the end of my post, it return the process id

Comment: @user2214609, so, what is going on with the client? Is there any exception or error?

Comment: No at all, the message not reach my client, the process start successfully but the client not get the server message, maybe it something with InstanceContextMode.PerSession ?

Comment: @user2214609, could you please post the complete code of the **service** to reproduce the issue you observed?

Comment: @user2214609, glad it helped! Could you please post the root cause of the issue?